# PHP Paging with variables ugly URLS

Tags: php, mysql

OK I have a large database I an querying LIKE SO

```
SELECT * FROM PricePaid WHERE PostCode LIKE '$loc%'
         ORDER BY Price DESC
     LIMIT $start,$perPage
```

I know how to do the paging links to work out the total records found and page through them. I am using the following code on my NEXT link :

```
<a href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."&start=$next'>NEXT</a>
```

Which works OK as it keeps my ?loc variable but the start variable duplicates.

This is how my url looks on the first page

```
 mysite/uk-property-prices.php?loc=l24
```

Then when I click my next page link the first time my url passes the start variable and the query displays page two

```
 mysite/uk-property-prices.php?loc=l24&start=1
```

But when I click next again I get this

```
mysite/uk-property-prices.php?loc=l24&start=1&start=2
```

Now I know this works but after a while my URL gets stupidly long LIKE so

```
mysite/uk-property-prices.php?loc=l24&start=1&start=2&start=3&start=4
```

What AM I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the query string as well.  All you're doing is appending more and more variables each time.

You will need to parse the query string, replace the value that you want to replace, and re-build the URL.  PHP has already parsed it for you in `$_GET` (assuming you don't need duplicate values).  Untested, but try this:

```
$newQueryParts = $_GET;
$newQueryParts['loc'] = 3;
$urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo 'http://', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $urlParts['path'], '?', http_build_query($newQueryParts);
```

Don't forget to consider the protocol as well.  Your site might use HTTPS in the future.  Also, they way you are interpolating variables directly in your query implies that you might be open to SQL injection attacks.  Always use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem.

Comment: I don't remember exact name, but you can get just script name (without GET arguments) and use it instead of 'REQUEST_URI'

Comment: @Lashane Not always.  You need to get it from `$_SERVER` in the case of rewrite rules.

Comment: Thankyou Brad for your detailed explanation much appreciated. I remember doing it in the past though I am going to have a go at your suggestion and see how I get on

Answer (score 0):

You're using `'REQUEST_URI'`, which will naturally contain the address of the page you're on, so if your visiting   `http://example.com/somescript.php?foo=bar` in your browser, `REQUEST_URI` will be `/somescript.php?foo=bar`.

Since you spit out that into your html's `href` parameters, then slap on MORE parameters, you naturally start building up longer and longer urls:

```
1st request    /somescript.php?foo=bar&start=1
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---request uri for #2
2nd request    /somescript.php?foo=bar&start=1&start=2
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---request uri for #2
3rd request    /somescript.php?foo=bar&start=1&start=2&start=3
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^request_uri for #3
```